# Missing Image second time using button

Tags: java

When I run through this the first time it works perfectly fine, but if I do it again the pane pops up with the size of the image, but the image does not show. I have tried debugging, but it is not giving me any sign as to why is is not adding the picture. What am I missing here? The structure of this is panel -> applet -> pane -> panel -> label and after first button use button is added to label.

```
bx.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent t) {

        gameimage =null;

        JFileChooser file = new JFileChooser();
        file.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
        file.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(true);
        if(file.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            int width;
            int height;

            File f = file.getSelectedFile();

            try {
                BufferedImage bimg = ImageIO.read(new File(f.getAbsolutePath()));
                width = bimg.getWidth();
                height = bimg.getHeight();
                String fname = f.getAbsolutePath();
                gameimage = new JLabel("", new ImageIcon(fname), JLabel.CENTER);
                gameimage.setVisible(true);
                gameimage.setSize(width,height);
                gameimage.setOpaque(true);                                       
                pane = new JScrollPane(px, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

                px.removeAll();
                px.revalidate();
                px.repaint();
                px.add(gameimage);

                ap.getContentPane().add(pane);
                pane.getViewport().add(px);

                ap.revalidate();
                ap.repaint();
                px.revalidate();
                px.repaint();
                gameimage.revalidate();
                gameimage.repaint();


            } catch(IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
             System.out.println("not working");
        }                                                                                          
    }
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't leave the catch block empty. At least logs the exception. It may give you the cause of your probem.

Comment: I noticed that and changed it already. Ill put updated code in.

Comment: It is not catching anything though. Just ran through it real quick.

Comment: I am still lost on this